# jQuery increment input's name's array index for new input element

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I've got a form inside of a table, something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tbody class="rowAdder">
<tr>
  <td><input name='info[5]' /></td>
  <td><input name='other_info[5] /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I want to clone the 'tr' element and in the clone I want to increment the index values.

PHP natively treats input names with "[]" as arrays. But I haven't found any way to easily play with that index value in jQuery.

I know I can use `("input[name$=']']")` to find all elements on the page with names ending in ']' but that doesn't help me. I won't always know what the "name" element will look like, so using a cumbersome string index method won't work alone. Although, perhaps an even more cumbersome method will.

I just want to find the names that are arrays and increment them when adding a row. I hope there is a simple, elegant way to do it.

```
var $array_inputs = clone.find("input[name$=']']");
```

That works to get the correct elements, although it is clunky. Now I need to increment 5's to 6's

Comment: you could build a string markup and increment on that on the concatenation, or clone the object like you said and traverse to change the name

Comment: But there is no method to get current index value?

Comment: what do you mean? one function to do it all? no. just traverse the intial markup, get the first index, from then on, increment on that by whatever event you need to, (`click, etc..`), or just simple initialize a simple counter `1`, since in the beginning you'll start at one anyway

Comment: To traverse the initial markup, I need to get the objects that have array names. If their array indexes were seen as some kind of jquery property then I could increment them easily.

Comment: simple, if the page initial has already several rows, then get their count (row count), from that count, that will be your starting point

Comment: Actually, total row count may work. But I still need to rebuild names for the cloned inputs and I am hoping there's a way that doesn't involve string parsing.

Comment: please note I updated my question. the table wasn't showing because I forgot to indent it properly.

Comment: okay i'l draft an answer should be up in a bit

Comment: Why not to remove the `index`, just `<input name='info[]' />`? In this way, the index will increment automatically and in PHP, you can get all data you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which is the **best** way but clearly, it can be done using a bit of this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input name='info[5]' /></td>
  <td><input name='other_info[5]' /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var last_child = $('table tbody tr:last-child'); // point the last row
    var children_input = last_child.children('td:eq(0)').children('input'); // get the input tag
    var index_num = children_input.attr('name'); // get its attr name
    var get_index = index_num.split('[').pop().split(']').shift(); // extract the index
    alert(get_index);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That looks pretty good. The code I'm writing is inside of `$(".rowChanger").on("click", ".appendRow", function() {`, so `$(this)` is the `tbody.rowChanger`. In which case I suppose I could use $(this).children().last() to get the last TR. Note the tr has 2 inputs.

Comment: @ButtleButkus yep, you can implement it using that, and then just point it to the first td children input, then get the attribute name, I assume, `info[5]` will always match `other_info[5]` right?, the important thing anyway is get the last index, so that will give you the starting point in which next number you will increment

Comment: Thanks and if I wanted to get the row count inside my `$('tbody.rowChanger')`, how would I do it that way? I tried $(this).length but it didn't work. It always says 1 (perhaps not updating with added rows).

Comment: Perhaps I've gotten that: `$(this).children().length;`

Comment: @ButtleButkus yes its indeed children().length